# How to do eternity-infinity sign?

Tags: iphone

I couldn't make my infinity sign on my phone. Does anyone know how to make an infinity sign on iPhone phones?
[infinity](https://oleex.com/how-to-do-eternity-infinity-sign-%E2%88%9E/)

Comment: Do you wish to enter this: ♾ ?

Comment: the link you included has an answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rely on third-party solutions (keyboards) like the one mentioned by @TomGewecke, use the built-in functionality for Text Replacements, as mentioned in the article you already linked to.

- First, copy the Unicode symbol, e.g. from [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+221E).
- Go to the Settings app -> General -> Keyboards -> Text Replacement -> create a new one with the + button in the top right.
- Paste the symbol in the Phrase field, and an appropriate term in the shortcut. I decided to go for the HTML entity `&infin;` since that works in Markdown as well: ∞, but you can definitely choose a shorter/easier one.

  [image]
- Save the text replacement, and now whenever you type `&infin;` the keyboard auto-complete suggestions will offer you to replace it with ∞:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

To make that and many other symbols, download an app like Unicode Pad.

Comment: This is the crux of any answer how to do this, copying the unicode character from an app (safari / web app / native app) and then pasting it is the way to get these characters if you don't use a keyboard that allows / maps the character you wish from the 137,993 unicode v 12 defined glyphs.